# Barra de Búsqueda no busca en android.widget.ListView (Obtengo Títulos de Array)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Tengo una **barra de búsqueda** que debería de buscar en mi `listview`, pero no es así, no busca nada por mucho que escriba.
Pulso en la lupa y se abre, escribo pero no busca nada.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Antes me buscaba bien los titulos de mi `ListView`, que los obtenía de aquí:

```
    String[] titulo = new String[]{
        "Android Studio",
        "Java",
        "Xml",
        "Otra Prueba",
};
```

Pero mi `ListView` ya no obtiene los titulos de ahí, ahora he modificado mi `ListViewAdapter` para que obtenga los títulos de ***array***

Así funciona mi código ahora:

`ListViewAdapter`:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] titulos;
    int[] imagenes;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    int idListaTitulos;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] titulos, int[] imagenes, int idListaTitulos) {
        this.context = context;
        this.titulos = titulos;
        this.imagenes = imagenes;
        this.idListaTitulos = idListaTitulos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return titulos.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtTitle;
        ImageView imgImg;

        String[] titulos = context.getResources().getStringArray(idListaTitulos);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
        imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_image);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews
        txtTitle.setText(titulos[position]);
        imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Y mi `clase`:

```
public class cocobuzz2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    MaterialSearchView searchView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;


    String[] titulo = new String[]{
            "Android Studio",
            "Java",
            "Xml",
            "Otra Prueba",
    };

    int[] imagenes = {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cocobuzz2);

        final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_coco2);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, titulo, imagenes, R.array.titulo1);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {
                switch (posicion) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cocobuzz2.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cocobuzz2.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cocobuzz2.class);
                        startActivity(c);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), cocobuzz2.class);
                        startActivity(d);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //If closed Search View , lstView will return default
                final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_coco2);
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(cocobuzz2.this, titulo, imagenes, R.array.titulo1);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {
                    List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (String item : titulo) {
                        if (item.contains(newText))
                            lstFound.add(item);
                    }

                String[] titulo = lstFound.toArray(new String[0]);

                    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(cocobuzz2.this, titulo, imagenes, R.array.titulo1);
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    //if search text is null
                    //return default
                    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(cocobuzz2.this, titulo, imagenes);
                    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_item,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Y ahora al haber añadido que obtenga los títulos de ***array*** (values-string) *-titulos1-* ya mi buscador no busca nada, así que imagino que mi error está aquí:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String item : titulo) {
                    if (item.contains(newText))
                        lstFound.add(item);
                }

// Al añadir esta linea ya me buscaba, PERO, cuando cambie la forma de obtener los títulos, dejó de hacerlo.

                    String[] titulo = lstFound.toArray(new String[0]);

// ---

                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(cocobuzz2.this, titulo, imagenes, R.array.titulo1);
```

Mi ***String*** con su ***array***

```
    <resources>

...
        <string-array name="titulos1">
            <item>Android Studio</item>
            <item>Java</item>
            <item>Xml</item>
            <item>Otra Prueba</item>
        </string-array>
    </resources>
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 3:** para @StefanNolde 07/02/2016

***clase***

```
    public class Cocobuzz2 extends AppCompatActivity {
        MaterialSearchView searchView;
        IndexAdapter adapter;

        // elimina la declaración fija de los datos que ya implementaste como arreglo en los recursos
        ArrayList<String> titulo;

        ArrayList<Integer> imagenes;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_cocobuzz2);

1.//////////// borrado <Integer> ya que no se utiliza

            imagenes = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Integer pos :

2.////////////////////// añado new int[]
                    new int[]
                    {
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            }) {
                imagenes.add(pos);
            }
            final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_coco2);
            //agrega aqui el código para llenar 'titulo' con datos

3.//////////// borrado <String> ya que no se utiliza

            titulo = new ArrayList<>();


            for (String tit : getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos1)) {
                titulo.add(tit);
            }
            // aqui es el UNICO lugar donde instamos un nuevo adapter


4.//////////////////////////// añado new int[]

                              adapter = new IndexAdapter(this, new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3});

            lista.setAdapter(adapter);

            lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {

                    // Como durante la búsqueda el contenido de tu arreglo va cambiando,
                    // eligir actividad por indice
                    // aquí quedo resto de código antiguo
                    switch ((Integer) adapter.getItem(posicion)) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cocobuzz2.class);
                            startActivity(a);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cocobuzz2.class);
                            startActivity(b);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cocobuzz2.class);
                            startActivity(c);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cocobuzz2.class);
                            startActivity(d);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

            searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSearchViewShown() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                    //If closed Search View , lstView will return default
                    adapter.clear();
                    adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
                }
            });

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {

5.//////////// borrado <String> ya que no se utiliza

                        List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList<>();


                        for (String item : titulo) {
                            if (item.contains(newText))
                                lstFound.add(item);
                        }

                        // usemos otro nombre de variable para mas claridad
                        // aun que diferenciemos entre this.titulo y titulo, así queda mas obvio
                        String[] subTitulo = lstFound.toArray(new String[0]);
                        // de nuevo, quedemos con el mismo adapter.
                        adapter.set(subTitulo);
                    } else {
                        //if search text is null
                        //return default
                        // y de nuevo ;)
                        adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
                        return true;
                    }

6./////////////////  he añadido return true;

                    return true;
                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar,menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            searchView.setMenuItem(item);
            return true;
        }

        class IndexAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            Context context;
            ArrayList<Integer> item;
            LayoutInflater inflater;
            //int idListaTitulos;

            public IndexAdapter(Context context, int[] id) {
                super();
                this.context = context;

7.//////////// borrado <Integer> ya que no se utiliza

                this.item=new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i : id) item.add(i);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return item.size();
            }

            // con getItem devolvemos la posición en la lista original
            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return item.get(position);
            }

            // usemos itemId para el imageId
            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return imagenes.get(item.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView txtTitle;
                ImageView imgImg;

8.//////////////////////// he borrado esta línea -> String[] titulos = context.getResources().getStringArray(idListaTitulos);

                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

                // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
                txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
                imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_image);

                // Capture position and set to the TextViews
                txtTitle.setText(titulo.get(item.get(position)));
                imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes.get(item.get(position)));

                return itemView;
            }

            public void set(String[] items){
                item.clear();
                for(String it :items){
                    if (titulo.indexOf(it)>-1) item.add(titulo.indexOf(it));
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void clear() {
                item.clear();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te pondría un comentario solo para esto pero disculpa por no hacerlo, no puedo por faltas de puntos. ¿Al poner un break point y depurar la aplicación al menos entra dentro o ni siquiera se inmuta?

Comment: yo uso buscadores en mi aplicación y me anda sin problema, pero no estoy seguro de como ajustarlo a tu list view, ya que yo uso un ExpandibleListView, aunque creo que debería ser similar. te agrego la respuesta

Comment: ¿Tienes dos listViews diferentes en la vista? (R.id.listview_shi y R.id.lstView)

Comment: Quizá el código que debas comparar sea el de la vista, y no el Java.

Comment: Eso está correctamente, creo que el error está en el Java @pablo

Comment: ¿Has probado lo del debug?

Comment: Acabo de añadir más información a mi pregunta, que he estado mirando por dónde podía tener el error y creo que es donde comento en mi pregunta, también he añadido un gif

Comment: y si en ves de darle otro adaptador modificas la lista. y usas oNotifyChanged?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747553/listview-not-updating-with-notifydatasetchanged-call Si quieres mira este problema es similar

Comment: gracias pero prefiero no modificar tanto mi código y encontrar el error que cometo @DanielORTIZ

Comment: Vale , aunque yo diria que uses "addTextChangedListener" este te ayuda detectar mejor las entradas de texto quizás te ayude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando cambian tus resultados de búsqueda, tu agregas un nuevo Adapter. Así no puedes garantizar que la vista se da cuenta que hay un cambio en los datos.

Lo que tienes que hacer es actualizar los datos **dentro** del `Adapter` que agregaste en `onCreate` y luego llamar a `notifyDataSetChanged()`. No compartiste la implementacion de tu Adapter, pero imaginando que usaste ArrayAdapter como subclase, trata eso:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String item : titulo) {
                    if (item.contains(newText))
                        lstFound.add(item);
                }

                lista.getAdapter().addAll(lstFound);
                lista.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                //if search text is null
                //return default
                lista.getAdapter().clear();
                // aqui pasas un arreglo con tus datos iniciales con que construies el adapter de cero usualmente
                lista.addAll(tuColleccionPorDefecto);
                lista.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            return true;
        }
```

Para cambiar el arreglo fijo a carga de títulos de los recursos tienes que cambiar algunas cosas. En el `Adapter` no tienes `getResources()`, así tienes que buscarlos desde `Activity`o `Fragnment`cuando construyes el adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cocobuzz2);

    final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_coco2);
    String[] titulos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos1);
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, titulos, imagenes);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Eso debería ser el **unico** lugar donde instas el adapter.
Para cambiar el contenido de la lista luego siempre llamas a este adapter por ejemplo como:

```
            // lstFound es tipo List
            lista.getAdapter().addAll(lstFound);
            lista.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

o para borrar los valores:

```
            lista.getAdapter().clear();
            lista.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**actualizado**

Tu adapter se ve bien a la vista (depurar en una pregunta no es tan seguro como en studio ;) ). En tu actividad hay problemas, como te dije, el adapter deberías instar **una vez** en `onCreate` y luego actualizarlo no mas con datos:

Para hacer tu aplicación vamos a tener que trabajar más en equipo. Necesito que compruebes los resultados de tu búsqueda con un `Log.d("RESULTADO BUSCAR", ...)` donde recibes los resultados para asegurarse que eso esta fuera de problemas.

**actualizado**
Como el método `clear()` en el `ArrayAdapter` no esta implementado, implementamos un propio adapter basado en BaseAdapter (como lo hiciste originalmente). Esta vez aun lo creamos como "inner class", así puede acceder los campos de la actividad, eso nos facilita el trabajo y usamos puros indices en el adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cocobuzz2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    MaterialSearchView searchView;
    IndexAdapter adapter;

    // elimina la declaración fija de los datos que ya implementaste como arreglo en los recursos
    ArrayList<String> titulo;

    ArrayList<Integer> imagenes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cocobuzz2);

        imagenes = new ArrayList();
        for (Integer pos :
                new int[]
                {
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        }) {
            imagenes.add(pos);
        }
        final ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_coco2);
        //agrega aqui el código para llenar 'titulo' con datos

        titulo = new ArrayList();


        for (String tit : getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos1)) {
            titulo.add(tit);
        }
        // aqui es el UNICO lugar donde instamos un nuevo adapter


                          adapter = new IndexAdapter(this, new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3});

        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int posicion, long l) {

                // Como durante la búsqueda el contenido de tu arreglo va cambiando,
                // eligir actividad por indice
                // aquí quedo resto de código antiguo
                switch ((Integer) adapter.getItem(posicion)) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent a = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cocobuzz2.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent b = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cocobuzz2.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cocobuzz2.class);
                        startActivity(c);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Cocobuzz2.class);
                        startActivity(d);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewShown() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSearchViewClosed() {
                //If closed Search View , lstView will return default
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {

                    List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList<>();


                    for (String item : titulo) {
                        if (item.contains(newText))
                            lstFound.add(item);
                    }

                    // usemos otro nombre de variable para mas claridad
                    // aun que diferenciemos entre this.titulo y titulo, así queda mas obvio
                    String[] subTitulo = lstFound.toArray(new String[0]);
                    // de nuevo, quedemos con el mismo adapter.
                    adapter.set(subTitulo);
                } else {
                    //if search text is null
                    //return default
                    // y de nuevo ;)
                    adapter.set(titulo.toArray(new String[0]));
                    return true;
                }

                return true;
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_buscar,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView.setMenuItem(item);
        return true;
    }

    class IndexAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<Integer> item;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        //int idListaTitulos;

        public IndexAdapter(Context context, int[] id) {
            super();
            this.context = context;

            this.item=new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i : id) item.add(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return item.size();
        }

        // con getItem devolvemos la posición en la lista original
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return item.get(position);
        }

        // usemos itemId para el imageId
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return imagenes.get(item.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView txtTitle;
            ImageView imgImg;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_title);
            imgImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_image);

            // Capture position and set to the TextViews
            txtTitle.setText(titulo.get(item.get(position)));
            imgImg.setImageResource(imagenes.get(item.get(position)));

            return itemView;
        }

        public void set(String[] items){
            item.clear();
            for(String it :items){
                if (titulo.indexOf(it)>-1) item.add(titulo.indexOf(it));
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void clear() {
            item.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando usas esta clase, Studio te va reclamar que el `R` no esta importado, eso tienes que agregar dependiente del paquete que usas.

He revisado los errores que marcaste, el principal es el `import` del `ListViewAdapter`. Actualmente hay una clase con este nombre declarado más la clase interna. Voy a cambiar el Nombre para desambiguear.

**actualizado**
Se me olvidó que `Arrays.asList` tiene sus problemas en Android. lo remplacé con código mas vintage. En el switch se necesitaba un cast.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53220/discussion-on-answer-by-stefan-nolde-barra-de-busqueda-no-busca-en-android-widge).

Answer (score 1):

Ya que veo, que no has recibido ayuda, te compartiré el buscador que YO uso (esta implementado para ExpandibleListView).
En simples palabras, es un FILTRO, que va ocultando-mostrando solo algunos datos de la lista, que coincidan con el filtro.
En mi aplicación, filtro la lista con checkboxs, pero también desde una "Lupa" (como en tú caso) y voy dejando visible solo lo que escribo en el EditText.
Trataré de dejar sólo lo que necesitas, ya que yo uso modelos para estructurar cada item de la lista... y te resolveré las dudas que vayas preguntando.

1°.- Cambia tu Adaptador de:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
```

por esto, con la librerias y variables de acontinuación:

```
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
...
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
...
private List<ingresaAcaTuArray> trx, trxs;
private ItemFilter filtro = new ItemFilter();
public Integer posicionUltimoGrupoExpandido;        //debe ser publico para que sea llamado desde la actividad
```

donde ingresaAcaTuArray, es el modelo o componente, que define el cuerpo que tendrá cada item de la lista.

2°.- Creación del componente ingresaAcaTuArray

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ingresaAcaTuArray implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID=100L;

    private String  string1, string2, stringn;

    private int int1=0, int2=0, intn=0;

    public TransaccionTerminal(
            String string1,
            String string2,
            String stringn,
            int int1,
            int int2,
            int intn
    ) {
        super();
        this.string1 = string1;
        this.string2 = string2;
        this.stringn = stringn;
        this.int1 = int1;
        this.int2 = int2;
        this.intn = intn;
    }

    public String getString1() {
        return string1;
    }
    public void setString1(String string1) {
        this.string1 = string1;
    }

    public String getString2() {
        return string2;
    }
    public void setString2(String string2) {
        this.string2 = string2;
    }

    public String getStringn() {
        return string2;
    }
    public void setStringn(String stringn) {
        this.stringn = stringn;
    }

    public int getInt1() {
        return int1;
    }
    public void setInt1(int int1) {
        this.int1 = int1;
    }

    public int getInt2() {
        return int2;
    }
    public void setInt2(int int2) {
        this.int2 = int2;
    }

    public int getIntn() {
        return intn;
    }
    public void setIntn(int intn) {
        this.intn = intn;
    }


    //Retorna true, si el texto "busqueda", esta dentro del contenido
    public boolean contiene(String busqueda){
        return getContenido().toUpperCase().contains(busqueda.toUpperCase());
    }

    //recupera todo el texto del item del listview
    private String getContenido(){
        return string1 + ' ' +
            string2 + ' ' +
            stringn + ' ' +
            int1 + ' ' +
            int2 + ' ' +
            int3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Algo{" +
            "string1='" + string1 + '\'' +
            ", string2='" + string2 + '\'' +
            ", stringn='" + stringn + '\'' +
            ", int1='" + int1 + '\'' +
            ", int2='" + int2 + '\'' +
            ", intn='" + intn +
            '}';
    }

    public Map<String, String> toHashMap(){
        Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("string1", string1);
        parametros.put("string2", string2);
        parametros.put("stringn", stringn);
        parametros.put("int1", ""+int1);
        parametros.put("int2", ""+int2);
        parametros.put("intn", ""+int3);
        return parametros;
    }
}
```

3°.- Agregar los métodos del BaseAdapter, esta bien si lo pegas en la penultima línea, entre los 2 corchetes que cierran.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filtro;
}

private class ItemFilter extends Filter{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence paramerosStr) {
        FilterResults resultados = new FilterResults();
        List<ingresaAcaTuArray> listaResultante = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject paramerosJO = new JSONObject(paramerosStr.toString());

            String busqueda = "";
            if(paramerosJO.has("busqueda"))
                busqueda = paramerosJO.getString("busqueda");

            for(ingresaAcaTuArray trx : trxs) {
                if (busqueda.length() > 0) {
                    if (trx.contiene(busqueda)) {
                        //Log.d(TAG, "busqueda: " + busqueda);
                        listaResultante.add(trx);
                    }
                } else {
                    listaResultante.add(trx);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        resultados.values = listaResultante;
        resultados.count = listaResultante.size();
        return resultados;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        trx = (ArrayList<ingresaAcaTuArray>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

4°.- Unir el editText(en mi caso materialEditText) con el adaptador (por limite de texto no agregaré el layout) y declarar adaptador (en tu caso ya lo hiciste y se llama adapter)

```
    //en el onCreate o onCreateView, vinculamos el materialedittext del layout a la actividad o fragment
    busquedaMet = (MaterialEditText)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.busqueda_met); //buscar por
    ...
    //Luego definimos como buscar
    busquedaMet.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            filtrarLista();   //muestra la lista filtrada
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });
```

5°.- El método filtrarLista:

```
private void filtrarLista(){
    try {
        if (adapter.posicionUltimoGrupoExpandido != null) {
            terminalesSinVisitaElv.collapseGroup(adapter.posicionUltimoGrupoExpandido);
            adapter.posicionUltimoGrupoExpandido = null;
        }

        try {
            JSONObject parametrosJO = new JSONObject();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(busquedaMet.getText())) {
                parametrosJO.put("busqueda", busquedaMet.getText());                                                //GUARDA TEXTO BUSQUEDA
            }

            adapter.getFilter().filter(parametrosJO.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

He quitado mucho codigo propio, por lo que me pude haber eliminado algo demas, avisame si falta algo

Comment: He estado mirando tu código y es bastante diferente al mio, y me he liado mucho, me es bastante complicado solucionar mi problema guiándome de tu código, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero sigo sin poderlo solucionar @Maguz he editado mi pregunta a ver si así me podéis ayudar mejor

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que no estás actualizando los valores del array de Strings "titulo", por lo tanto el Adapter está recibiendo siempre los mismos valores del comienzo.

Una solución podría ser crear otra variable que contenga los valores actualizados y pasarla al adaptador:

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText != null && !newText.isEmpty()) {
                List<String> lstFound = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String item : titulo) {
                    if (item.contains(newText))
                        lstFound.add(item);
                }

                String[] titulo-actual = lstFound.toArray(new String[0]);


                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(cocobuzz2.this, titulo-actual, imagenes);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else {
                //if search text is null
                //return default
                adapter = new ListViewAdapter(cocobuzz2.this, titulo, imagenes);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Como al adaptador hay que pasarle un objeto de tipo String[], hay que convertir la List en array mediante el método toArray.